# Facebook wall post

Tags: php, facebook

I use the below code to post on my friends wall.

```
$facebook->api('/'.$item.'/feed?'.$token,'post',$attachment);
```

It works but the post on his wall shows his name and photo.

How can I show MY PHOTO and MY NAME in the post????

This is how I generate the token:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id='.APP_ID.'&client_secret='.APP_SECRET.'&redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com/pages/Cosmetics/167231286678063?sk=app_233227910028874&grant_type=client_credentials');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,0);

$token = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: And is the access token yours? Or his?

Comment: It is an offline_access token

Answer (score 1):

You should set authentications token to the one generated using your login details.

you have to set an access token before you can evoke api eg: `$facebook->setAccessToken($token);` this token is created when user logs in to you app.  This user will be the author of all posts made by api.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you forgot `access_token=` ?

```
$facebook->api('/'.$item.'/feed?access_token='.$token,'post',$attachment);
```

Comment: Nope its in the $token variable.

Comment: I don't have a problem with posting the message I just want to post it as me not with my friend's name and photo.